# Is it possible to use switch statement inside class member function and get accessor?

Tags: c#, class, function, get, switch-statement

Here is the class (relax, it's just an example and not intended for concrete use):

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {
    }

    public string Size
    {
        get
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: return 100;
                        break;
                case 1: return 500;
                        break;
                case 2: return 1000;
                        break;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an "Unreachable code detected" error on the break keyword.  Is it even possible to write switch statements inside a class or class member function?  Or,  am I stuck with if-else blocks?

**Based on the feedback below, I see I made a silly error, with return preceding the break**

Comment: you are getting a unreachable code on the break because the code is unreachable, the return ensures that. You can just remove the break statements and everything should work fine.

Comment: @juergend: That's not the problem. Look at the error message.

Comment: “Unreachable code” is a warning. Are you actually getting any error?

Comment: @DavidHope Nice. THe `return` on the same line as the case label threw me off :/

Comment: @user717236 - +1 for owning up to the mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a unreachable code on the `break` because the code is unreachable.  The `return` ensures that.  You can just remove the `break` statements and everything should work fine.

You can rewrite the switch in either of these two ways:

```
switch(index)
{
  case 0: return 100;
  case 1: return 500;
  case 2: return 1000;
}
```

or

```
int value = 0;
switch(index)
{
   case 0:
     value = 100;
     break;
   case 1:
     value = 500;
     break;
   case 2:
     value = 1000;
     break;
}
return value;
```

Comment: see my comment above for explanation

Answer (score 7):

The "unreachable code" warning is because your `break` statements are immediately following a `return` statement. Therefore, the `break` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a variable to save your number, after switch, you return variable.

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {

    }

    public string Size
    {
        get
        {
            int num=0;
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: num= 100;
                    break;
                case 1: num= 500;
                    break;
                case 2: num= 1000;
                    break;
            }
            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? How is that better than the original code?

Comment: at least this code wouldn't give you the unreachable code issue

Comment: @svick I don't say I have the best answer, I just give one of solutions. :)